# Criptografar SQLite3

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, criptografia, sqlite3

Existe uma forma gratuita para criptografar banco de dados SQLite3?

Já vi alguns softwares proprietários bastante caros.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Dá um pouco de trabalho porque não tem nada prontinho para usar com o PHP (e boa parte das tecnologias), mas existem bibliotecas que podem ser integradas ou substituir o SQLite padrão:

- [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher)
- [FreeSQLiteEncryption](https://github.com/shenghe/FreeSQLiteEncryption)
- [botansqlite3](https://github.com/OlivierJG/botansqlite3)
- [SQLiteCrypto](http://www.andbrain.com/product/sqlitecrypto/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigadão, vou pesquisar...